# Readfile() has started displaying on page

Tags: php, readfile, php-ziparchive

Part of what's being displayed:

```
    PKd�wL��� ���/images/image_0.jpg��ex\K��1昙�3�133���;ffff����Ԇ�����w�̼߳�cw��딎�$��Z�������&QRTB�|>��E��M5���|�~b��)�o�3�� �>s���o�'���^B�O��V ����@���Q?S#(�� 6���v4���8����vvV�sy}#�_ �O��s�o���L�7Fv.F&�ol��WV.V��?�����g�W!�/w!�������K�oLL�1`���G�p�X���T�>C�@��L��)q���s��3�g�8�p�O�?
```

I'm trying to download images into zip file, this is what i've got so far:

```
if (count($headers->images) > 0) {
    $counter = 0;
    $zip = new ZipArchive();
    $tmpFile = "tmpFolder/tmp" . strtotime("now") . ".zip";
    $zip->open($tmpFile, ZipArchive::CREATE);
    foreach($headers->images as $key => $images) $zip->addFromString("/images/image_" . $counter++ . ".jpg", file_get_contents($images));
    $zip->close();
    if (file_exists($tmpFile)) {
        $fname = basename($_POST["titleZipFile"] . ".zip");
        $size = filesize($tmpFile);
        header("Content-Type: archive/zip");
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$fname");
        header("Content-Length: " . $size);
        ob_end_clean();
        readfile($tmpFile);
        //unlink($tmpFile);
        echo "<div id='reportMessage'><p>You have successfully save images. Please go to your folder " . $_POST["titleZipFile"] . ".zip<p></div>";
    }
}
```

if I remove the unlink($tmpFile); line then the tmp zip is actually generated and has the images inside the zip. However it's not actually showing the zip downloading in browser.

Does any one have any ideas why this could be happening?

Comment: why not just redirect them to the zip file path and let the browser handle it?

Comment: @KaffineAddict will that download the zip in their browser automatically?

Comment: Yes I believe it does but I have one more alternative

Comment: Looks like you are trying to output a binary file AND html all together?

Comment: @IncredibleHat So i'm trying to generate the zip file and then readfile($tmpFile) to download. Then echo the report message.

Comment: You can't really do _both_

Comment: What @PatrickQ said... you kind of need to delegate one or the other, and if you need to download and display something in a web browser... you might have luck with some ajax and redirects with a hidden iframe... but, it gets messy.

Answer (score -1):

Try to change the header for the content type to the following. I think the header is causing the browser problems with interpreting what it is supposed to do. Try the following type.

```
 header('Content-type: application/zip');
```